# How do I remove a taxonomy from one post?

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

With

```
wp_set_object_terms($postId, $termsList, $taxonomy, true );
```

I set taxonomy on my posts (products for woocommerce, from an external feed).
How I can remove the taxonomy for one post, when termsList is empty?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(  empty( $termsList) ){ 
 
    wp_remove_object_terms( $postId, 'term-to-remove', $taxonomy ); 
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remove_object_terms/